# |Laravel Encryption| "Payload is Invalid" error thrown when grabbing multiple entries in database but not when grabbing one entry

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-blade

**Solution:**
This problem stemmed from me trying to decrypt something that was stored in my database as plain text. You obviously can't decrypt something that isn't encrypted. Duh! I feel like an idiot. But I'm going to leave this post up as a reminder to all those out there coming across the same issue. Remember to check you database to make sure you're decrypting something thats encrypted! :P

**Original Post**

So I'm new to encryption and decryption so I'll try and document everything I can in explicit detail as not to confuse myself or anyone reading this post.

**Goal:** When I submit a form, I want to encrypt the `$request->note`, and I want to decrypt right before letting the user see the 'note'.

**Progress So Far:** I have successfully encrypted the note upon form submission using model mutators. I am able to show the user in the 'show' page the single decrypted note. However on the 'index' page I'm not able to show the notes and I'm getting thrown a "Payload is invalid" error. Which is weird because i'm decrypting successfully on the show page. Only in the foreach loop of the index page am i getting this error. I did a die/dump on my Collection (`$notes` variable) and i'm successfully grabbing the entries out of the database, and the collection is returning the encrypted note along with the collection. Only when calling `$note->note` in a foreach loop am I getting an error. So i'm kind of confused. What would make the show page, when grabbing a single entry from the database not return any errors, but grabbing multiple entries from the database would return this error?

Error I'm getting. Redacted the site name and replaced with "SiteName".

> The payload is invalid. (View: /Volumes/Secondary
>   HDD/Sites/SiteName/resources/views/notes/index.blade.php)

Here's my code with some comments to make things a bit easier. Note that I'm posting a lot of code. This is to illustrate the show page not causing me any issues, and how to index page is. I'm not sure where the problem lies. So I'm throwing out as much information I can on the subject by posting all the relevant code.

**Note.php (Model)**
    namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Note extends Model
{

    // Define the relationship between Notes and Steps
    public function step() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Step');
    }

    // Encrypt the Note
    public function setNoteAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['note'] = Crypt::encryptString($value);
    }

    // Decrypt the Note
    public function getNoteAttribute($value) {
        return Crypt::decryptString($value);
    }
}
```

**index() Method in NotesController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    // Assign the user id a variable
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    // Find all the notes written by the user
    $notes = Note::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);

    // Return the view with all the notes
    return view('notes.index')->withNotes($notes);
}
```

**index.blade.php foreach loop**

```
@foreach($notes as $note)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $note->step->number }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ substr(strip_tags(str_replace("&nbsp;", ' ', $note->note)), 0, 100) }}
            {{ strlen(strip_tags(str_replace("&nbsp;", ' ', $note->note))) > 100 ? "..." : "" }}
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
            {!! Form::open(['route' => ['notes.destroy', $note->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
                <a href="{{ route('notes.edit', $note->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>

                {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm']) !!}

            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**show() Method in NotesController.php**

```
public function show($id)
{
    // Grab the Note by the ID from the Database
    $note = Note::find($id);

    // Assign the Authenticated User ID to a variable
    $user_id = Auth::User()->id;

    // Check the Authenticated User ID with the Note's User ID in the Database
    if(!$user_id === $note->user_id) {
        // Throw a 403 Error if it doesn't match
        return response(view('errors.403'), 403);
    }

    // Return the view with the Note
    return view('notes.show')->withNote($note);
}
```

**show.blade.php without a foreach loop since I'm only grabbing one entry from the database**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
        <h3>Your Note</h3>
        <p>
            About: Step {{ $note->step->number }}
            <br>
            Created On: {{ date('M j, Y @ H:i', strtotime($note->created_at)) }}
            <br>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <p>
            {{ $note->note }}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is because you are calling Crypt::decryptString on an already mutated property.

Comment: It was because I had an entry in my database that wasn't encrypted. This was left over from the previous tested entries prior to adding the encryption mutator. Remember to always check you database. :/ lol